# Setting up the triple integrals for a solid given by $y + x = 4$ and $16 - 4z^2 = y^2$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to set up all six triple integrals to find the volume of the solid that lies in the first octant bounded by the coordinate planes, the plane 
$y + x = 4$, and the cylinder $16 - 4z^2 = y^2$.

$3$D graph

[image]

I've been able to set up the triple integrals for every other combination except for $dydxdz$ and $dydzdx$, which I am struggling to find the bounds for. I know the volume is $8\pi - 32/3$, but I keep getting an incorrect answer when I set up and calculate dydxdz and dydzdx.

Here's my equation for the projection onto the $xz$-plane, but I'm not sure it is correct/complete:

$xz$-plane projection?

[image]

I'd appreciate any help regarding how to find the bounds of dydxdz and dydzdx.

Comment: Why are you asking the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2984584/help-setting-up-the-triple-integrals-dydxdz-dydzdx-when-given-equations-of-a-s) again? Posting a question, especially *exactly the same question*, multiple times will not increase the possibility of an answer.

Comment: @mrtaurho: Actually it's not exactly the same question, since it's a different kind of cylinder here.

Comment: @Hans, but close enough to be duplicate, is it not? I mean, I can easily see five more questions in the near future just like these two with small differences if OP is preparing for exam or doing homework.

Comment: Yes, @HansLundmark is right, they're different problems, with two different solids with different equations; I just happen to have trouble finding dydxdz and dydzdx in both of them.

Comment: @HansLundmark Oh, I just realised it. The same layout confused me. I would say it is not a good way to just copy-and-paste the question and then just changing a few numbers afterwards.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, everyone. I agree that they are formatted similarly with the same general layout. If you think I should remove one or both, I'd be more than willing to do so.

Comment: What is the second cutting plane in the image at r9ght? It is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Narasimham the light blue plane is y + x = 4. The solid is in the first octant, so it's bounded by the coordinate planes x = 0, y = 0, and z = 0.