# How to change the order of this triple integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am stuck with one of the question in my homework. I need to change the order of this integral $\int^1_0\int^{4-y^2}_0\int^{2-y}_0f(x,y,z)dzdxdy$ into $dydxdz$

I have already try to draw the solid, and i know that the height of the solid is 2 so the integral will be $\int^2_0\int^{x=?}_{x=?}\int^{y=?}_{y=?}f(x,y,z)dydxdz$

I am stuck on projecting the solid onto the x-z plane, therefore i cannot change the order of the triple integral properly, can somebody help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The given integral doesn't make sense. You are saying that $y$ goes from $0$ to $4-y^2$.

Comment: oh that is a mistake, i have corrected it, thank you for noticing

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2984584/setting-up-the-triple-integrals-for-a-solid-given-by-yz-2-and-x-4-y2

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to do this algebraically rather than geometrically.

- What are all the possible values of $z$ that appear in the original integral? You've already answered this: $0\le z\le 2$.
- Given a fixed $z$, what are all the possible values of $x$ that appear? In this particular case, the values of $x$ and $z$ don't seem to affect each other, so perhaps the simple $0\le x\le 4$ is correct. (In this algebraic method, later steps can allow us to go back and fix earlier steps if we're wrong.)
- Finally, given a fixed $z$ and a fixed $x$, what are all the possible values of $y$ that appear? The inequalities ($0\le y\le1$ and) $0\le x\le4-y^2$ and $0\le z\le2-y$ in the original integral give us ($0\le y\le1$ and) $y\le\sqrt{4-x}$ and $y\le2-z$. The values of $y$ that satisfy all of these inequalities are $0\le y\le\min\{1,\sqrt{4-x},2-z\}$.

Therefore the resulting formula will be
$$
\int^1_0\int^{4-y^2}_0\int^{2-y}_0f(x,y,z)\,dz\,dx\,dy = \int_0^2 \int_0^4 \int_0^{\min\{1,\sqrt{4-x},2-z\}} f(x,y,z)\,dy\,dx\,dz.
$$
Notice how this algebraic method works perfectly well even when the shape of the region of integration is inscrutable.

Comment: Sorry i just found out that i made a silly mistake.$y$ should go from 0 to 2 in the original integral. Therefore,is the answer just simply $\int^2_0\int^4_0\int^{\min(2,\sqrt{4-x},2-z)}_0f(x,y,z)dydxdz$

Comment: Great, and indeed $\min\{2,\sqrt{4-x},2-z\} = \min\{\sqrt{4-x},2-z\}$ here.